# Grafana - Modifying "All" label in JSON Model

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am currently working on a Grafana project and I need to translate the "**All**" results into "**Tous**".

[**Example of what I need**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOHKV.png)

The one that is currently working is because it's got a limited number of results

[**Working - filter with limited results**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GujTo.png)

The other variables (filters) however are more dynamic and will evolve with time. Therefore, there are unlimited possible results and it's options array is empty.

[**Not working - filter with unlimited results**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edaBz.png)

Everytime I change the "All" text value of my "fonds" filter (the one not working) to "Tous", it resets to "All" as soon as it has a chance

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan